# C# EF Core QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync strange behaviour

Tags: c#, generics, entity-framework-core, expression

I have a generic repository to whom I pass an `Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> filter`. For example this expression looks like:

```
filterExpr = part =>
    (filter.ProductId != null ? filter.ProductId == part.ProductId : true) &&
    (filter.SerialNumber != null ? filter.SerialNumber == part.SerialNumber : true);
```

In the repository I call `QueryableExtensions.FirstOrDefaultAsync(filterExpr)` on a DbSet that I've got from DbContext:

```
this.dbSet = context.Set<TEntity>()
// ....
IQueryable<TEntity> query = dbSet;
return query.FirstOrDefaultAsync(filter);
```

It works well if either `ProductId` or `SerialNumber` or both are defined. If all filter properties are `null`, I would expect the expression to evaluate to `true`and therefore `FirstOrDefaultAsync` to return the first Element in the queried table. But instead EF core seems to try to load the whole table. My memory consumption goes up a couple of GB and then I receive a timeout. 
When I perform a UnitTest using an InMemoryDatabase I get `null` as result which is also not what I expect.

Edit: Here is the UnitTest as requested.

```
    [Fact]
    public void GetPartWithEmptyFilterTest()
    {
        var optionsBuilder = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<ProductStatusContext>();
        optionsBuilder.UseInMemoryDatabase("GetPartWithEmptyFilterTest");
        var context = new ProductStatusContext(optionsBuilder.Options);

        var part = new Part { SerialNumber = "abcdef" };

        context.Parts.Add(part);
        context.SaveChanges();

        var unitOfWork = new UnitOfWork(context);
        var service = new PartService(unitOfWork, null, null);

        service.GetPartAsync(new PartFilterResource()).Result.Should().Be(part);
    }
```

Edit2: My current workaround is to test all filter Properties for a `null` value and evaluate the filte only if at least on propery is different from `null`

```
private bool AllPropertiesNull(object obj)
{
    return !obj.GetType().GetProperties().Any(propInfo => propInfo.GetValue(obj) != null);
}
```

And then:

```
if(filter != null && AllPropertiesNull(filter))
    filterExp = part => true;
```

But I'd like to avoid this.

Comment: Can you show your unit test?

Comment: Try Take(1) instead, but you need the OrderBy - else it will be random what is first. Else use SingleOrDefault

Comment: @DIlshodK I added the test code but I don't think this helps. However, I could live with it if return null in production instead of giving me a timeout.

Comment: @FrankNielsen Passing an empty filter to the method generelly is not making any sense at all and should not happen in production, so it doesn't matter which object is returned exactly. It's just that the API shoul be robust enough to deal with this scenario without crashing. I could check all filter properties for a null value and then skip the filtering but this adds a lot of unnecessary code. My question is more like "Am I doing something wrong or is this an issue with EF that I should file on GitHub?", It's not about a workaround. Thanks for your suggestions nevertheless.

Comment: What EF Core version are you using?

Comment: Treat it as a requirement for the API. If no filters is defined, return/throw an error saying filter is needed.

Comment: Do you still get the same behaviour if you ask for eg FirstOrDefault(), or FirstOrDefault(e=> true)? I also wonder about ordering because first without orderby makes no sense so is there a large amount of data being downloaded because ef didn't think it could orderby on the server so it downloads all db to do it on the client? What sql is being generated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on my experience with EF Core, the query translator is trying to eliminate the constant predicate expressions in order to produce criteria (or no criteria at all) similar to if you were using conditional `Where`.

However it seems to handle properly binary expressions (`&&`, `||`) and fail doing that for conditional `? :` expressions. You may report it to their GitHub issue tracker, but since they are working on EF Core 3.0, I don't think it would be addressed in earlier versions. And 3.0 is still in state where many things doesn't work, hence cannot be used to evaluate whether this would work or not in the final version.

The workaround I would suggest (and seems to work well in all versions) is to use the equivalent `||` based conditions, e.g.

```
filterExpr = part =>
    (filter.ProductId == null || filter.ProductId == part.ProductId) &&
    (filter.SerialNumber == null || filter.SerialNumber == part.SerialNumber);
```

Comment: Thank you very much, this does the trick and your explanation also sounds reasonable. Unfortunately now I cannot use my `bool CheckFilter<T>(T filterProp, T checkProp)` as I intended in the beginning, but I can life with this.