# How to write a If condition inside a Where clause in ef core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, if-statement, entity-framework-core

I am working in a asp.net core web API with EF Core version 5.0.

I wrote a query with a if condition.

```cs
if (incomingFacilities.Count() > 0)
```

then I need to filter the facilities those are in the `incomingFacilities` list.

If `(incomingFacilities.Count() < 0)` I do not need to filter. I have to get only 6 distinct facility list.

But write below code. The issue is I need to repeat same code again and again.

So I thing It is better to the if condition inside

```cs
.Where(x => (incomingFacilities.Count() > 0 ) ? 
            (incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode)) :
            (x.FacilityCode > 0 )),
```

Here I did the First part correctly, (ie: If `incomingFacilities.Count() > 0` then do filter.

But the second part is `if incomingFacilities.Count() < 0` then there's no need to filter, just send the list of facilities (only no of 6 facilities those are distinct)

```cs
// this code is correct, but same code repeated 
if (incomingFacilities.Count() > 0)
{
    var hotels = await _context.Hotels
        .Where(i => (i.DestinationCode == request.Destination))
        .Select(i => new HotelListHotelVm
        {
            // removed some
            HotelFacilities =  i.Facilities.Select(x => new HotelListHotelVm.HotelListFacilityVm {
            Id = x.Id,
            FacilityGroupCode = x.FacilityGroupCode,
            HotelFacilityGroupDescription = x.FacilityGroup.Description,
            FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode
        })
        .Where(x => (incomingFacilities.Count() > 0 ) ? (incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode)) : (x.FacilityCode > 0 )),
        })
        // rest
        ;
}
else
{
    var hotels = await _context
        .Hotels
        .Where(i => (i.DestinationCode == request.Destination))
        .Select(i => new HotelListHotelVm
        {
            // removed some
            HotelFacilities = i.Facilities.ToList().Distinct().Take(6)           
                .Select(x => new HotelListHotelVm.HotelListFacilityVm {          
                    Id = x.Id,                                                      
                    FacilityGroupCode = x.FacilityGroupCode,                                                     
                    HotelFacilityGroupDescription = x.FacilityGroup.Description,          
                    FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode                                           
                })
        })
        // rest
        ;
}
```

`.Where(x =>(incomingFacilities.Count() > 0 ) ? (incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode)) : (x.FacilityCode > 0 )),`
Here,

I did `If incomingFacilities.Count() > 0`  then, use where clause.

But I don't know  how to say, If **not** `incomingFacilities.Count() > 0` then do a list of facilities with distinct value and take only 6. Like this `HotelFacilities = i.Facilities.ToList().Distinct().Take(6)`

```cs
    .Select(x => new HotelListHotelVm.HotelListFacilityVm {          
        Id = x.Id,                                                      
        FacilityGroupCode = x.FacilityGroupCode,                                                     
        HotelFacilityGroupDescription = x.FacilityGroup.Description,          
        FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode                                           
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

EF Core query translator is smart enough to evaluate expressions which use pure client side arguments and remove filter expressions which are known to be `true` in advance, like `true || some_expr`.

So all you need is to write your filter as follows:

```cs
.Where(x => !incomingFacilities.Any() || incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode))
```

This will produce two different SQL queries - one with filter and one without depending of whether the parameter `incomingFacilities` contains elements or not.

Comment: From which EF Core version?

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv From 2.0 if recall correctly. And fixing/improving in next versions.

Comment: Actually I think they always create parameters. But maybe I have missed something.

Comment: @SvyatoslavDanyliv This was one of the "cool" things i liked in EF Core, as it eliminates the need of building conditional `Where` like in EF6. I wrote the following https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57520807/c-sharp-ef-core-queryableextensions-firstordefaultasync-strange-behaviour/57521906#57521906 in 2019, but pretty sure it existed even from the very beginning. Not sure if they fixed conditional operator, but `||` and `&&` work for sure.

Comment: Yes, it works. Looks like they forgot to do the same with QueryFilter ;)

Answer (score 0):

Good morning,

if I understand you correctly you want to get a `List<HotelListHotelVm>`, but the content changes if there are elements in `incomingFacilities`.

First I would get rid of the `.Count()` extension here and use `.Any()` instead. This is for performance reasons, as `.Count()` would only stop once you have iterated over the whole list. `.Any()` instead stops once it has found one element in your `incomingFacilities` and returns the respective `bool` if there is anything in your list, or not.
If you don't need the count of items of the `incomingFacilities` list and only check if there is anything in it `.Any()` is the better choice (like in your code). If you really need the count value, then use `.Count()`.

Based on your comments, try the following (again, untested). First initialize a variable which holds your hotels as a list (or an array, or whatever). Then you check if you have any `incomingFacilities`. If so, you get the values from the database and compare it against the facility code. After that you filter your list for all elements which indeed HAVE `HotelFacilities`. If there are some values in it, `hotels` is not empty.

In the next step you look into the `hotels` list. If you have values in it, you don't have to retrieve anything from the database, if not - you get the first 6 elements from the database.

If `incomingFacilities` is empty from the beginning, so is `hotels` and therefore the code will retrieve 6 elements from the database.

I hope I understood it correctly now.

```
List<HotelListHotelView> hotels = new List<HotelListHotelView>(); 

if (incomingFacilities.Any())
{
    hotels = await _context.Hotels
                           .Where(i => (i.DestinationCode == request.Destination))
                           .Select(i => new HotelListHotelVm
                           {
                               HotelFacilities =  i.Facilities.Where(x => incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode))
                                                              .Select(x => new HotelListHotelVm.HotelListFacilityVm 
                                                                                   {
                                                                                       Id = x.Id,
                                                                                       FacilityGroupCode = x.FacilityGroupCode,
                                                                                       HotelFacilityGroupDescription = x.FacilityGroup.Description,
                                                                                       FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode
                                                                                   })
                           }).Where(h => h.HotelFacilities.Any())
                             .ToList();   
}

if(!hotels.Any())
{             
    hotels = await _context.Hotels
                           .Where(i => (i.DestinationCode == request.Destination))
                           .Select(i => new HotelListHotelVm
                           {
                                   HotelFacilities = i.Facilities.Distinct()
                                                                 .Take(6)           
                                                                 .Select(x => new HotelListHotelVm.HotelListFacilityVm 
                                                                     {          
                                                                         Id = x.Id,                                                      
                                                                         FacilityGroupCode = x.FacilityGroupCode,                                                     
                                                                         HotelFacilityGroupDescription = x.FacilityGroup.Description,          
                                                                         FacilityCode = x.FacilityCode                                           
                                                                     })
                           }).ToList();
}
```

Comment: Hi, This line `HotelFacilities =  i.Facilities.Where(x => incomingFacilities.Contains(x.FacilityCode))` return [ ] if incomingFacilities is [ ]. 
BUT  If incomingFacilities is [ ] I need, 6  HotelFacilities. (not [ ] or not all the HotelFacilities)

Comment: I guess your ```i.Facilities``` is something you get from your database? So this line checks if some entries in your database are part of the ```incomingFacilities```. This presumption has to be fulfilled to get a result back. If it returns nothing, then you don't have any database related entries which are in your incoming facilities list. Do I understand it correctly that, if this assumption is not fulfilled and the return value is nothing / zero facilities, then you want to get the 6 first entries of your database?

Comment: If user needs to filter the facilities I need to send hotels with those facilities,( Examples He select WiFi, then I need to send hotels with WiFi facility. ) otherwise I need to send any of 6 facilities for each hotel. got it?
That's why I asked, If incomingFacilities is null then send any of 6 hotels

Comment: I updated the code, try if this solves your problem now.